# URL title to Entry ID on Channel Entries tag

Tags: expressionengine

I'm trying to use the "URL title to Entry ID" plugin to feed the entry_id parameter into a Channel Entries tag, but can't figure out a way to get the ID information inserted early enough in the template parsing order.

This doesn't work - it picks up no entry ID, and so displays all entries:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{exp:url_title_to_entry_id parse="inward" url_title="{last_segment}"}" dynamic="no"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please note: you will get a better response using the ExpressionEngine  Answers site instead of general Stack Overflow: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a function tag as a parameter to another function tag.

So either you have to pass the {exp:url_title_to_entry_id} result as an embed variable to another template that holds the channel:entries tag, or you have to use tag pairs so that one function tag, wraps the other and uses variables.

url_title_to_entry_id doesn't allow for tag pair, so either use the embed technique, or use another add-on.

**BUT**, you don't need the add-on at all...

```
{exp:channel:entries url_title="{last_segment}" dynamic="no"}
   {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

[reference.](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#url-title)

I'd also suggest added required_entry="yes" and limit="1" and then add {if no_results}...{/if} conditional inside. This will prevent it outputting all entries if it can't find a match.